# Conflict between two scripts' links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to apply an image filtration technique and also want to make the image opens in a fancy box, I added the code and made links to the scripts that I need but while adding the below script link :

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

above the filtering links and script, the filter works but the fancy box doesn't want to work and while adding the same link above fancy box links and script, the fancy box works but the filter doesn't want to work...

Here is some of my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
        <!-- Add jQuery library of fancybox -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="image-library/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="image-library/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="image-library/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image-library/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image-library/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="image-library/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image-library/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="image-library/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="image-library/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            openEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = '';
            }
        });


        /*
         *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
         */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
        */
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                arrows : false,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });

        /*
         *  Open manually
         */

        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'iframe.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : '1_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    });
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="filter/filtrify.css">
<script src="filter/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script src="filter/script.js"></script>
<script src="filter/filtrify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
var ft = $.filtrify("cbp-rfgrid", "placeHolder");


$("a#1").click(function() {
    ft.trigger({ categories : ["Photography"] });
});

$("a#2").click(function() {
    ft.trigger({ categories : ["Retouching"] });
});

$("a#3").click(function() {
    ft.trigger({ categories : ["CGI"] });
});

$("a#4").click(function() {
    ft.trigger({ categories : ["Oranges"] });
});

$("div#triggers > a").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .addClass("selected")
        .siblings("a")
        .removeClass("selected");

});

$("a#reset strong").click(function() {
    ft.reset();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $('#triggers .selected').removeClass("selected");
});
$("li").click(function() {
    ft.reset();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $('#triggers .selected').removeClass("selected");
});


});

</script>

</head>
```

Also you can refer to the below link to see it alive with the fancy box problem...

http://arqqa.net/aostudio-beta/

Comment: You are using two versions of jQuery at the same time..

Answer (score 1):

In your live example, first you are calling upon jQuery (1.10.1), then you are embedding the Fancybox scripts, followed by the script to execute fancybox.
After your actions section you are calling upon another jQuery (1.8.2). Having multiple instances of jQuery is likely to give you the conflict.

- Use jQuery only once, and make it the first script to be executed.
- Make sure your actions are the last script to be executed.
- Place your actions in an external javascript file.
- Place javascript before the closing body tag in your document.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can confirm that this won't work with later versions of jQuery (1.0.7). I downloaded the demo found at

http://tutorialzine.com/2011/02/converting-jquery-code-plugin/

and replaced the jQuery lib reference to a later version and the ddl fails to function.

NB - I'm also aware that I'm not providing an answer here, but in the infinite wisdom of the site administrators I'm not allows to comment without having reached the required  number of brownie points!

Answer (score 0):

you can use two versions of jquery at the same time:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/